# Python: Pandas pd.read_excel giving ImportError: Install xlrd >= 0.9.0 for Excel support

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to read a `.xlsx` with pandas, but get the follwing error:

```
data = pd.read_excel(low_memory=False, io="DataAnalysis1/temp1.xlsx").fillna(value=0) 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Vineeth/PycharmProjects/DataAnalysis1/try1.py", line 9, in <module>
    data = pd.read_excel(low_memory=False, io="DataAnalysis1/temp1.xlsx").fillna(value=0)
  File "/Users/Vineeth/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Vineeth/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 230, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "/Users/Vineeth/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 263, in __init__
    raise ImportError(err_msg)
ImportError: Install xlrd >= 0.9.0 for Excel support
```

I've also tried

```
data = pd.read_excel("DataAnalysis1/temp1.xlsx", low_memory=False).fillna(value=0)
```

And I Still get the same error.

Background: I'm trying to extract an excel file with multiple worksheets as a dict of data frames.I installed xlrd version 0.9.0 and the latest version(1.1.0) but I still get the same error. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try listening to the error message and installing the `xlrd` package?

Comment: Yes, I installed the `xlrd` package. Edit: I tried to import the package, but python gives me a `import xlrd
ImportError: No module named xlrd` error

Comment: I'm guessing you installed for a different python version.

Comment: @cs95, just got same error message, point is why i got this error message when i am just using function of this library, why didn't pandas installed all its dependency library. itself :(

Answer (score 157):

As @COLDSPEED so eloquently pointed out the error explicitly tells you to install xlrd.

```
pip install xlrd
```

And you will be good to go.

Comment: I exactly had the same issue, I had to force re-install xlrd.
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall xlrd

Comment: @TamasSzuromi Unfortunately I keep having the same error message after trying both of your commands : `Install xlrd >= 0.9.0 for Excel support
` :/

Comment: same here (on v 1.1.0)...and I cannot import it either, as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227745/importerror-install-xlrd-0-9-0-for-excel-support-when-using-pd-readexcel-to/51286813

Comment: tech-prism's answer below is more modern.

Comment: If you see this message: _Your version of xlrd is 2.0.1. In xlrd >= 2.0, only the xls format is supported. Install openpyxl instead._ Please see message from @tech-prism and go for `pip install openpyxl`

Answer (score 122):

Since December 2020 xlrd no longer supports xlsx-Files as explained in the official [changelog](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html). You can use `openpyxl` instead:

```bash
pip install openpyxl
```

And in your python-file:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.read_excel('path/to/file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

Comment: That is the only answer that worked for me!  Thanks! I hope they accept your answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. My program ran fine on Python 3.9 with a newer version of pandas (1.2.3) but trying to make it compatible with python 3.6 I can only get pandas up to 1.1.5 which must still use XLRD as the default engine. Thank you for this answer!

Comment: For me in the terminal: pip install openpyxl  command, solved the issue. No need to set:  engine='openpyxl' in the read_excel method. But works with it , too. Just make sure its installed on your path.

Answer (score 38):

Either use:

```
pip install xlrd
```

And if you are using conda, use

```
conda install -c anaconda xlrd
```

That's it. good luck.

Comment: I've installed xlrd and shows up when I run `pip freeze` however still having same error message...

Answer (score 9):

If you are in ubuntu this work for me:

```
python3 -m pip install openpyxl
python3 -m pip install xlrd
```

Answer (score 7):

This happened to me after I ran a script with cProfile a la `python3 -m cProfile script.py` even though xlrd was already installed and had never thrown this error before. it persisted even under `python3 script.py`. (Granted, I agree this wasn't what happened to OP, given the obvious import error)

However, for cases like mine, the following fixed the issue, despite being told "requirement already met" in every case.

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
pip install --upgrade xlrd
```

Pretty confounding stuff; not sure if cProfile was the cause or just a coincidence

The following should work, assuming your `pip install` operated on python2.

```
python3 -m pip install xlrd
```

Answer (score 6):

I was getting an error

> "ImportError: Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support"

on Pycharm for below code

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
print(df2.head(3))
print(df2.tail(3))
```

Solution : `pip install xlrd`

It resolved error after using this.
Also no need to use "`import xlrd`"

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:
For Python 3

> pip3 install xlrd --user

For Python2

> pip install xlrd --user

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will be helpful for someone, but I had the same problem.
I wrote `pip install xlrd` in the anaconda prompt while in the specific environment and it said it was installed, but when I looked at the installed packages it wasn't there.
What solved the problem was "moving" (I don't know the terminology for it) into the `Scripts` folder of the specific environment and do the `pip install xlrd` there.
Hope this is useful for someone :D

Answer (score 2):

Was getting the error while I was using jupyter.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlrd'
...
ImportError: Install xlrd >= 0.9.0 for Excel support
```

it was resolved for me after using.

```
!pip install xlrd
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same problem and took 2 hours to figure it out.

1. pip install xlrd (latest)
2. pip install pandas (latest)
3. Go to C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages and check for xlrd folder (if there are 2 of them) delete the old version
4. open a new terminal and use pandas to read excel. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and none of the above answers worked. If you go into the settings (CTRL + ALT + s) and search for project interpreter you will see all of the installed packages. Click the + button at the top right and search for xlrd, then click install package at the bottom left.

I had already done the "pip install xlrd" command from the file location of my python.exe before this, so you may need to do that as well. (you can find the file location by searching it in windows search bar and right click -> open file location, then type cmd into the file explorer address bar)

Answer (score 1):

**This can be because your required libraries are been installed in Python environment instead of Spyder.**

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Actually, the problem is that even after installing packages/libraries using pip these packages are not integrated with IDE. So, need to add libraries specifically to the ide.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to install xlrd & pandas packages. Then try below code.

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd

xl = pd.ExcelFile("fileName.xlsx")
print(xl.parse(xl.sheet_names[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the "xlrd" lib

For Linux (Ubuntu and Derivates):

Installing via pip:
*python -m pip install --user xlrd*

Install system-wide via a Linux package manager:
*sudo apt-get install python-xlrd

Windows:

Installing via pip:
*pip install xlrd

Download the files:
https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, is the machine has an older version of xlrd installed separately, and it's not in the "..:\Python27\Scripts.." folder.

In another word, there are 2 different versions of xlrd in the machine.

[image]

when you check the version below, it reads the one not in the "..:\Python27\Scripts.." folder, no matter how updated you done with pip.

```
print xlrd.__version__
```

Delete the whole redundant sub-folder, and it works. (in addition to xlrd, I had another library encountered the same)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue trying to use xlrd in jupyter notebook. I notice you are using a virtual environment and that was the key to my issue as well. I had xlrd installed in my venv, but I had not properly installed a kernel for that virtual environment in my notebook.

To get it to work, I created my virtual environment and activated it.

Then...   `pip install ipykernel`

And then... `ipython kernel install --user --name=myproject`

Finally, start jupyter notebooks and when you create a new notebook, select the name you created (in this example, 'myproject')

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your python or python3 can see xlrd installation.  I had a situation where python3.5 and python3.7 were installed in two different locations.  While xlrd was installed with python3.5, I was using python3 (from python3.7 dir) to run my script and got the same error reported above.  When I used the correct python (viz. python3.5 dir) to run my script, I was able to read the excel spread sheet without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @WojciechJakubas mentioned to install `openpyxl` instead of `xlrd`, I used  `openpyxl` and it worked.

> pip install openpyxl

```
import openpyxl
path = "path to file.xlxs"
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
length_col = sheet_obj.max_row
print("Length of rows : ", length_col)
```

I hope it will help lot of people in 2023.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me until I just uninstalled it first and reinstalled from scratch:

```
pip uninstall xlrd
pip install xlrd
```

Answer (score 0):

for people using e.g. Spyder in Windows: this error occurs because Spyder cannot locate your packages. They are indeed installed, but Spyder cannot find them.

how to fix:

1. run `pip install xlrd` in your command prompt. This will give following output:
   `Requirement already satisfied: xlrd in c:\users\USER\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (2.0.1)` This path is important as there the modules are installed, but the path is not linked to Spyder
2. In the Spyder GUI, go to "Tools" and click on "PYTHONPATH manager". A window opens
3. Click "+ add path" in the bottom left corner. Then, add the path that you found in step 1 by running "pip install xlrd"
4. save and relaunch Spyder. Now you should be good to go!

this solution is based on: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/python-on-spyder-modulenotfounderror-a-trick-51c058129e17