# ImportError: Install xlrd >= 0.9.0 for Excel support when using pd.readexcel to read .xlsx file : never happened before

Tags: pandas, xlsx

Something strange is going on. Just today when trying to read in a dataframe from an xlsx file:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('vlnew.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

I am getting the following error:
**ImportError: Install xlrd >= 0.9.0 for Excel support**

I am fully aware that plain and simple the instructions are to install xlrd, but I should not have to install xlrd when I was never getting this error before, and also, **xlrd only applies to the old .xls file format. I am using .xlsx.**

I can't understand why today all of a sudden this error is popping up. This is very strange indeed, at least to me.

**Update**:
When I execute this script in the Spyder IDE, I do not get the xlrd import error, but just today I ran this script in the Conda command prompt and only then does it report the xlrd error. Why are there inconsistencies between the Conda command prompt and Spyder IDE?

Answer (score 9):

Try writing following command into the terminal
`pip install xlrd`

And then import the xlrd alongside with pandas
`import xlrd` and `import pandas as pd`

Comment: BK, thanks for your reply. I will try this it out on my next dataframe file. For the time being I just execute the .py file using Spyder.

Comment: hi @banditok. , I installed xlrd (v 1.1.0) but I cannot import it ... any idea? thanks

Comment: cannot import xlrd.... outputs `
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlrd' ` when I run `import xlrd`

Answer (score 2):

I was getting an error "ImportError: Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support" on Pycharm for below code

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
print(df2.head(3))
print(df2.tail(3))
```

Solution : pip install xlrd

It resolved error after using this.

Also no need to use "import xlrd" in program

Answer (score 2):

(2021.01.18)

NOTICE: the current version of "xlrd" reads only ".xls" files
to read ".xlsx" files install **openpyxl** package.

Just do it in your phyton frame (my is "repl.it") writing

**import xlrd**

or

**openpyxl**_

NOTICE: the current version of "xlrd" reads only ".xls" files

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by you and others correctly that xlrd needs to be installed, for using read_excel we require xlrd package.

This might be one of the possibility of compatibility difference between spyder and conda is that you might be using different conda environments for Spyder and prompt, one of which might contain xlrd package and other did not this has happens usually when we use  different virtual environments for our work , it has happened to me many times.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

`pip install --upgrade xlrd`

Answer (score 0):

juste type

```
pip install xlrd
```

and use it like  this

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_excel('titanic3.xls')
```