# Run xlsx docs into spyder

Tags: python, spyder, xlrd, openxlsx

Folks, i am trying open a .xlsx doc on spyder using:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\lucas.francklin\Desktop\Programação\LM automatica\Teste.xlsx') 
print (df)
```

them it give me:

```
Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd
```

I tried :

```
pip install xlrd and !pip install xlrd
```

it give me:

```
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

C:\Users\lucas.francklin\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\Python\python.exe: No module named pip

what can i do?

Comment: Have you restarted the kernel? Rebooting spyder is a reasonable way to do that.

Comment: Anaconda spyder? Did you try pip from Anaconda prompt? Start>>Anaconda>>Anaconda Prompt?  (or powershell)   It reads like you tried it from the python console...?

Comment: solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65592436/2375421